# Question was put on hold as opinion based

Tags: discussion

[If I use CMD + C on my iPhone the information is stored even after restart. But not on Notebook. Why?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273707/if-i-use-cmd-c-on-my-iphone-the-information-is-stored-even-after-restart-but)

The question is about the situation - where the same action works differently on iPhone and MacBook.

If someone know the difference of OS implementation for iPhone and MacBook for this case he can also answer this question. If not - than the question cannot be answered.

There is nothing to do with different opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Only Apple employees know why Apple decides to do something one way or the other, and they usually are not talking about it. That's why questions about why Aplle does this or that are off-topic (as documented in the help center).

Specifically for the linked question: this can be answered with "because Apple decided to implement it that way". You probably agree that this isn't really helpful.

Comment: I know that OS from Apple are not open source. There are sometimes the situation, that Apple employees, former employees etc. give some information. For example on some conferences. Maybe this question could be answered this way.

Comment: If not - it shouldn't  be closed (put on hold) as an opinion based as for me. Off-topic - maybe,  or maybe question, that cannot be answered.

Comment: @mikrodel You can always edit the question to get it more in line with the FAQ. It will then get placed into the review queue for reopened and reviewed by high-rep users of the site.

Comment: I updated my question. Lets see :)